# Data Analytics SQL Query method

Tags: sql-server-2014

I need every 13th row as new column. I am not sure how this can be done using Pivot or transpose. Number of rows are not fixed.

Please guide me the way.

Thanks

Data is as shown below where every 4 row gets repeated

ID    Value
AA     A
BB     B
CC     C
AA     D
BB     E
CC     F
AA     G
BB     H
CC     I

it should be as below

ID    Value1  Value2     Value3 
AA     A           D           G 
BB     B           E           H 
CC     C            F              I

Comment: Sample data and expected results please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `PIVOT`, something like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID CHAR(2), Value CHAR(1) )

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT *
FROM (
VALUES
( 'AA', 'A' ),
( 'BB', 'B' ),
( 'CC', 'C' ),
( 'AA', 'D' ),
( 'BB', 'E' ),
( 'CC', 'F' ),
( 'AA', 'G' ),
( 'BB', 'H' ),
( 'CC', 'I' )
)   x ( y, z )

SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [VALUE] ) rowId
    FROM @t
    ) x
PIVOT ( MAX( Value ) FOR rowId In ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) pvt
```

My results:

[image: Pivot results]

Comment: Thanks Bob. That is perfect and within no time... Thanks once again.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the query is not dynamic.